# Can't find an attorney to represent us

Tags: united-states

I've literally called over 300 plus attorneys and know for fact my wife and I have multiple that will pay out huge, one being Walmart, the other being a municipality for the corruption and malicious prosecution,and the other being a s.o. that told me on camera it was a landlords right to tell me he would kill me and my wife the day before we had eviction court.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: This is exactly the kind of opening lawyers hate. My thinking is that if a client already knows exactly how it all works, he doesn't need me.

Answer (score 5):

If 'literally 300' attorneys declined your case on the basis of a phone call, without looking into the details, I can see three options:

- You are unable to communicate the nature of your case clearly.
  In this posting, you mentioned complaints against a company, a municipality, and a landlord, plus being evicted. Focus on explaining *one* case.
  If you think you 'know for a fact' that you have several big payouts coming, there is the first problem. *Nobody* knows what a jury will decide. An attorney might hesitate to work for a client who does not understand this. Litigation is always a risk.
- All your cases actually lack merit, a lawyer sees this and you do not. Not knowing the cases, I cannot tell. (And no, you should not explain them in detail on the web. If they do have merit, posting your strategy hurts the cases.)
- Your state has a [vexatious litigant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexatious_litigation#United_States) list and you are on it. That would not prevent an attorney from taking your case, but it might make them hesitate.